# VB Script in jsp/HTML is no working in IE10 but works in below versions

Tags: java, html, jsp, vbscript, internet-explorer-10

VB script is not working in IE10 I have used the below code copying in .html file . when I double click on the .html file below file opens perfectly in IE8 but not in IE 10 . Please help

---

```
         <STRONG>New version of <SPAN STYLE="background-color:yellow"> v 2.10.12 </SPAN>,
        released on <SPAN STYLE="background-color:yellow"> 7th Mar 2008.</span>. </STRONG>            
    <BR><BR>
    <DIV ID="jwsReady">
    </DIV>
    <BR>
    <SCRIPT Language="VBScript">
    <!--
    Sub JWS
    ReadyHTML = ReadyHTML & "<br>Please remember to set up the"
    ReadyHTML = ReadyHTML & "<SPAN STYLE=""background-color:yellow"">Proxy</SPAN> for Java Web Start&copy;(JWS) as"
    ReadyHTML = ReadyHTML & "<SPAN STYLE=""background-color:yellow"">None</SPAN>, either: -"
    ReadyHTML = ReadyHTML & "<UL>"
    ReadyHTML = ReadyHTML & "<LI>during first access, when JWS prompts for proxy set up, or,</LI>"
    ReadyHTML = ReadyHTML & "<LI>by accessing the JWS program, either through the Start Menu"
    ReadyHTML = ReadyHTML & "[Start-&gt;Programs-&gt;Java Web Start-&gt;Java Web Start], or "
    ReadyHTML = ReadyHTML & "its shortcut on the desktop.<BR>"
    ReadyHTML = ReadyHTML & "In the menu File-&gt;Preferences, General tab, select the Proxy as"
    ReadyHTML = ReadyHTML & "   <SPAN STYLE=""background-color:yellow"">None</SPAN>.</LI>"
    ReadyHTML = ReadyHTML & "</UL>"
    ReadyHTML = ReadyHTML & "If you have any questions during setup, please contact the <a href=""mailto:XYZ@gmail.com?subject=Install Support"">dev group</a>."

    NotReadyHTML = NotReadyHTML & "<BR>"
    NotReadyHTML = NotReadyHTML & "<EM>Before Installation, please make sure you have closed all other programs.</EM><BR>"
    NotReadyHTML = NotReadyHTML & "Please choose default options all throughout<BR>"
    NotReadyHTML = NotReadyHTML & "After installing the runtime environment, you may be required to restart the machine."
    NotReadyHTML = NotReadyHTML & "If you have restarted, please visit this page again. If you have not restarted,"
    NotReadyHTML = NotReadyHTML & "please refresh this page."
    NotReadyHTML = NotReadyHTML & "If you have any questions during install, please contact the <a href=""mailto:xyz@gmail.com?subject=Install Support"">dev group</a>."

BothJREJNLP = "JWS installed, but version not detectable. Try <A HREF=""/rca/rca.jnlp"" STYLE=""color:blue;"">Client</A>. If you get any error(s), try <a href=""http://mpts.ctc.chrysler.com/jre/j2re-1_4_2_07-windows-i586-p.exe"">JRE v 1.4.2_06</a>." & NotReadyHTML & ReadyHTML
        On Error Resume Next
Document.All.jwsReady.innerHTML = BothJREJNLP 
    End Sub
    Call JWS
    -->
    </SCRIPT>
</DIV>
```

Comment: How *exactly* is it "not working"? What happens when you remove the `On Error Resume Next`?

Comment: try copying the code into text file and name it as html and try double clicking it in IE8  and IE 10 . It will not show the content in IE10 and it will show in IE8.

Comment: Why would anyone still be using VBScript in webdevelopment?

Comment: Its old code .. I need to change it such that it will work in IE10 . Please let me know if there is any way such that it will work in IE10.

Comment: If Not(IsObject(CreateObject("JavaWebStart.isInstalled"))) Then -- > I didn't paste these line which have if else conditions which check java versions and will show html accordingly. I have omitted those line's. I am not sure but javawebstart.isinstalled is in only VB script . If you have any other alternative please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue . I am not sure how it is working in IE10 no idea but its working with below fix

```
  Sub JWS
document.write()
    ReadyHTML = ReadyHTML & "<br>Please remember to set up the"
    ReadyHTML = ReadyHTML & "<SPAN STYLE=""background-color:yellow"">Proxy</SPAN> for Java Web Start&copy;(JWS) as"
    ReadyHTML = ReadyHTML & "<SPAN STYLE=""background-color:yellow"">None</SPAN>, either: -"
    ReadyHTML = ReadyHTML & "<UL>"
```

Yes just keeping document.write() worked like charm :) in IE 10.
VBScript works in IE10